# NestJs module depending on provider, ServiceLocator?

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

**Goal**

I am working in a module similar to SpringActuator (I need /health, /info, /metrics, etc), I need the module to be reused across several apps, but the logic to determine if the app is healthy or to get the app info is defined at the application itself, I want this actuator module to be agnostic of the application. So I need the application to import the module passing a provider that exists already at the application context.

**Implementation**

I used the ModuleRef (with strict option) to create something like a ServiceLocator, so that any app dependency could be resolved during module initialization.

The actuator module is imported like this

```
imports: [ActuatorModule.forRoot({ actuatorToken: ApplicationActuator })]
```

The ApplicationActuator is the class knowing if the app is healthy or not. This provider could have another dependencies internally (nested)

The ActuatorModule uses a factory approach to provide the service locator(FactoryHelper)

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'ActuatorFactoryHelper',
      useFactory: (moduleRef: ModuleRef) => new FactoryHelper(moduleRef, options.actuatorToken),
      inject: [ModuleRef],
    }
  ]
```

And finally my service uses the FactoryHelper like this

```
get actuator(): Actuator {
  return this.factoryHelper.instance;
}

constructor(@Inject('ActuatorFactoryHelper') private readonly factoryHelper: FactoryHelper<Actuator>) {}
```

This is how the FactoryHelper looks like

```
export class FactoryHelper<T> implements OnModuleInit {

   instance: T;

   constructor(
     private readonly moduleRef: ModuleRef,
     private readonly token: Type<any> | string | symbol,
   ) {}

   onModuleInit() {
     this.instance = this.moduleRef.get(this.token, { strict: false 
   });
  }
}
```

**Question**

I read in another threads that having a module depending on a provider is a bad practice, Is it a bad practice? what issues could I face? Is it a easier way of doing it?

**Notes**

- I tried using custom providers (useFactory) but nested dependencies got not resolved (they are not visible to the actuator module).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find the solution to your problem?